# Persist dialog or layout across different activities

Tags: android, dialog, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I have 2 activities; an **AuthenticationActivity** (which is the launcher) & a **MainActivity**.

The AuthenticationActivity layout is only shown when the user needs to log in, otherwise if the user is logged in, they're redirected to the MainActivity.

```
    if (userId != null && !userId.isEmpty()) { //User is signed in       
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    } else { //User isn't signed in
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);
    }
```

My main issue is that the MainActivity takes a bit of time to launch, so I need to display a non-cancelable dialog inside AuthenticationActivity, and also launch the MainActivity, once the MainActivity has completed rendering its views then the dialog created in the AuthenticationActivity is dismissed.

How can I achieve this?

**Important to note:** If possible I don't want to request the user for the 'Overlay permission', so other solutions other than displaying a dialog are welcomed

Comment: why your mainactivity is taking time to load?

Comment: since there are a no of operations to be done, I've done the best I can to optimize by lazy loading, calling only a few methods in onCreate, using ViewStabs etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should solve your problem:

```
if (userId != null && !userId.isEmpty()) { //User is signed in  
    yourDialog.show();     
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
        yourDialog.dismiss();
    }
} else { //User isn't signed in
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);
}
```

And dont forget to set `setCancelable(false)` to your Dialog

Answer (score 0):

Seen to Dialog has to bound to a Activity Window, so there is no way to show a normal dialog on different activities.

Back to your problem, compare to show a dialog as a Loading when MainActivity is not available to render, you should consider put that Loading in the MainActiivty, you shoud know render a loading view render so quick enough. so you may need to do is show a loading view before loading your own data.